# Getting error EEXIST when trying to install latest version of npm

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, logging, npm

Trying to deploy my nodejs app to Heorku.

Build is successful but getting the below error.

Tried to delete the file and then ru it but doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx.cmd: is outside C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```